# Boost Spirit Qi parser does not consume whole string expression?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

Assuming I have the following rule:

```
identifier %= 
        lexeme[
            char_("a-zA-Z")
            >> -(*char_("a-zA-Z_0-9")
            >> char_("a-zA-Z0-9"))
        ]
        ;

qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> identifier;
```

and the following input:

```
// identifier
This_is_a_valid123_Identifier
```

As the traces show the identifier is parsed properly and the attributes are set but the skipper starts one char after the first character of the string again:

```
<identifier>
  <try>This_is_a_valid123_I</try>
  <skip>
    <try>This_is_a_valid123_I</try>
    <emptylines>
      <try>This_is_a_valid123_I</try>
      <fail/>
    </emptylines>
    <comment>
      <try>This_is_a_valid123_I</try>
      <fail/>
    </comment>
    <fail/>
  </skip>
  <success>his_is_a_valid123_Id</success>
  <attributes>[[T, h, i, s, _, i, s, _, a, _, v, a, l, i, d, 1, 2, 3, _, I, d, e, n, t, i, f, i, e, r]]</attributes>
</identifier>
<skip>
  <try>his_is_a_valid123_Id</try>
  <emptylines>
    <try>his_is_a_valid123_Id</try>
    <fail/>
  </emptylines>
  <comment>
    <try>his_is_a_valid123_Id</try>
    <fail/>
  </comment>
  <fail/>
</skip>
```

I've already tried to use as_string in the lexeme expression which did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you complicate the expression. Can you try

```
identifier %= 
                char_("a-zA-Z")
            >> *char_("a-zA-Z_0-9")
        ;

qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> identifier;
```

This is about the most standard expression you can get. Even if you don't want to allow identifiers ending in `_` I'm quite sure you don't want such a trailing `_` to be parsed as 'the next token'. In such a case, I'd just add validation after the parse.

**Update** To the comment:

Here is the analysis:

- First off: `-(*x)` is a ***red flag***. It is never a useful pattern as `*x` already matches an empty sequence, you can't make it "more optional"

  > *(in fact, if `*x` was made to allow partial backtracking as in regular expression, you'd likely have seen exponential performance or even infite runtime; "luckily", `*x` is always greedy in Spirit Qi)*.

This indeed facilitates your bug. Let's look at your parser expression in the OP as lines 1, 2, 3.

- First, Line 1 matches `T`.
- The second line initially greedily matches `his_is_a_valid123_Identifier`.
- But that cannot satisfy the third line, so the `-(...)` kicks in and everything after line 1 is backtracked.
- ***However***: Qi

  - *does* backtrack the *cursor* (current input iterator) but
  - *does not* by default rollback changes to container attributes.

  Yes. You guessed it. `std::string` is a container attribute.

So what you end up is a succeeded match with length 1 and residu of a failed optional sequence in the attribute.

Some other backgrounders on how to resolve this kind of backtracking issue:

- [boost::spirit::qi duplicate parsing on the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869978/boostspiritqi-duplicate-parsing-on-the-output/13875183#13875183)
- [Parsing imperial values using boost spirit (qi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918275/parsing-imperial-values-using-boost-spirit-qi/15924194#15924194)
- [pass attribute to child rule in boost spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520649/pass-attribute-to-child-rule-in-boost-spirit/12527010#12527010)
- [Understanding Boost.spirit's string parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959270/understanding-boost-spirits-string-parser/21960981#21960981)

Comment: and why is it not possible to use the parser i posted?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't looked. I'm in the habit of reasoning towards the goal. "Organically grown" parser expressions might not even complete, and reasoning about them is... tough. However, see the **updated** answer. Cheers.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer! It a very good explanation!!